# Symfony Security - delete button in loop

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, security, button

I am wondering about the security of my application. I'm simply using twig loop to display all of my records in database. And everything is all right when I make separate site to display the details and there are buttons to e.g. delete this thing. It usually happens DELETE method and somebody can display only own details. But I want to have button to delete specific record in basic view where every records displayed e.g. next to title of item.

1. I cant do this by CreateFormBuilder because I cannot send the current id of the item from the form (or I just don't know how to do it). But is it secure? Everyone can change the id parameter of button and delete other record.
2. I can use AJAX and simply button in twig but this is the same case. Everyone can change e.g. data-id parameter in button and delete other record.

What I should to do in this situation? How you usually solve this problem?

Summarising I want to make a secure button to delete item next to each displayed record.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really boils down to what kind of app you want to build:

- more traditional app - with full page refresh/navigation cycle
- AJAX based - with all sorts of async calls to your server

In any case you choose, it is your responsibility to check whether the current user is authorized to make any change (deletion included) to an object. This comes as especially important in case of `id` being integer, which is predictable.

So, first, make sure your routes are protected from anonymous users, and second, make sure that you put in place permission strategy which allows/denies user's specific action.

Most of the permission-related stuff can be achived via **[Voters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html)**, but if you are really in need of heavy-lifting you can turn to **[ACL](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl.html)**.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to secure AJAX routes is to use JWT (json-Web-Token) (see this : [https://jwt.io/](https://jwt.io)) instead of random string token. This token is crypted with the user's information to ensure the person who clicked on the button is allowed to do someting (and the token is send with the request in header of the request).

Anyway, you have to send something to identify the id of the element you want to erase or modify in your database. I would personnaly implement this JWT system, but the access to the page where you can see and click on these buttons must be protected too. This way, you can assume that the users don't have bad intentions.

Theis bundle (https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#getting-started) can help you to implement this on symfony very easily (i'm new to this framework and i did this in a few hours - just a thing: if you use Apache, don't forget to allow override in your Apache configurations to allow the .htaccess of symfony to do his job, or headers will be strip by Apache - it makes me several hours to find why things did not work !).

Hope this will help !

Comment: @Patrick: Indeed, JWT is very well worth checking out for what you need...